# Conditional join SQL Server with condition

Tags: sql

I have tree tables like this: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui

I need to do this join
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAIQz.png)

```
Select * from table A lef join table B on A.A=B.A

left join table C on ***if*** C.col2= 1 then B.B=C.B if C.col2=0 then B.C=C.C
```

Is there any way to create the last join as a conditional join without became the query slow?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome Luis! Please respect forum's guidelines: avoid image (please post directly), format post, and provide info for a reproductible example ([details here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)) - and also precise your dbms

Comment: `left join table C on (C.col2= 1 AND B.B=C.B) OR (C.col2=0 AND B.C=C.C)`

Answer (score 0):

Using join with AND condition would work.

Select * from table A left join table B on A.A=B.A

left join table C on B.B=C.B and C.col2= 1

OR B.C=C.C and C.col2=0